# How to install wireless driver on Compaq nx6120 laptop

Tags: wireless, intel-wireless, compaq

Just installed Ubuntu 11.10 in my compaq nx6120 laptop. I turn on the wifi but it says "wireless disabled by hardware switch."

Is this a driver problem or is there any switch in laptop for enabling it? Please help

output of some commands are given below

**$ sudo lshw -C network****

```
*-network:0 DISABLED    
       description: Wireless interface
       product: PRO/Wireless 2200BG [Calexico2] Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 4
       bus info: pci@0000:02:04.0
       logical name: eth1
       version: 05
       serial: 00:12:f0:99:dd:dc
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ipw2200 driverversion=1.2.2kmprq firmware=ABG:9.0.5.27 (Dec 12 2007) latency=64 link=no maxlatency=24 mingnt=3 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bg
       resources: irq:21 memory:d0000000-d0000fff
  *-network:1
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: NetXtreme BCM5705M_2 Gigabit Ethernet
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: e
       bus info: pci@0000:02:0e.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 03
       serial: 00:14:38:00:ea:cb
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 66MHz
       capabilities: pm vpd msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=3.119 duplex=full firmware=5705-v3.24 ip=192.168.1.3 latency=64 link=yes mingnt=64 multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:16 memory:d0020000-d002ffff
```

I am a beginner please help.

Answer (score 0):

The model of laptop you have has a hardware switch that can be toggled to turn the wireless function on and off - it also has a LED on it to indicate status.

It is located on the top edge above the keyboard - third button along from the left hand side.

[Here is an image](http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/12136_div/12136_div.HTML) that should help you locate it.

Comment: thanks mark for replying.. but i have switched on that wireless button shown in the fig but it still showing "wireless disabled by hardware switch". If i need to install drivers for it pls tell me how to do it?

thanks agaun

Comment: hey good news .. now its working in my laptop
" rfkill unblock all " works for me

Answer (score 0):

Try shutting down(if not already off), disconnecting the power, remove battery(if it is a laptop), press power a few times to release stored energy, reinsert battery(if it is a laptop), reconnect AC power. Turn on computer. Worked for me. After trying multiple fixes I found on the internet I remembered reading this somewhere. My hardware was blocked via a hardware switch(fn+f8) which doesn't work in ubuntu(works with windows, but uninstalled windows). rfkill showed 0: phy0: Wireless Lan as Hard Blocked.